# Integrating a function raised to a power

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have this function while I tried to calculate rotational moment of spherical shell.

I got the following integral which I was unable to integrate:

$$\large\dfrac{\int_{-R}^{R} \left[\sigma 2\pi y \sqrt{(R^2 - y^2)} dy\right]}{\int_{-R}^{R} \left[\sigma 2\pi \sqrt{(R^2 - y^2)} dy\right]}$$

**
$\sigma$,$\pi$ , $R$ are constants. therefore it reduces to :**

$$\large\dfrac{\int_{-R}^{R} \left[y \sqrt{(R^2 - y^2)} dy\right]}{\int_{-R}^{R} \left[ \sqrt{(R^2 - y^2)}dy\right]}$$

now what we do? is there a short method of evaluation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integral in the numerator is zero, since the function you integrate is odd and the interval you integrate over is symmetric with respect to zero.

Comment: but how could that be? i cot this result when trying to find moment of inertia of shell. i took sphere as a combination of small cylinder discs and put the circle equation for height.

Comment: But since you just write those integrals for us without mentioning where you start or what you do, it is impossible to know for certain what you do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try a substitiution with $u = R^2-y^2$ and $du = -2ydy$ for the numerator. For the denominator you can use $y = R\sin(x)$ and $dy = R\cos(x)dx$.

Comment: How did you know that we have to put y = r* sin(x)

Comment: Because you can use the trigonometric substitution whenever $R^2-y^2$ ist written, as this will reduce to one term after this substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Put $y=Rsin(x)$ and then solve.Remember to change the limits as needed.

Comment: yes that i want to ask how you came to know that we have to do so?

Comment: just plug it in...basically its because 1-(sin x)^2=(cos x)^2